# How could I manipulate this array in Javascript for this kind of error checking?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

How can I make Javascript check an array and make sure that there's no error committed after the comma separating each element of the array .. For example a user may form an array with two commas in a row separating an element instead of one comma .. Not just comma , any other wrong input.

```
var cars=["Saab",,"Volvo","BMW"]; // Here , this array has an error , there's a double comma .
var cars=["Saab",*"Volvo","BMW"]; // this array has an error , there's an asterix.
var cars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];  // this array is the right one.
```

Here's the wrong array

What Javascript function or solution could I use to make sure an array is checked and no error is within it .. Only elements and separating commas with no space in between.

Your help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: You want to validate that a string is a valid javascript code ?

Comment: That already throws errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static code analyzer such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

The latter is available [as a JavaScript library](http://www.jshint.com/docs/#jslib) in addition to the web-hosted flavor.

Comment: ok .. but could you help as far as implementing the solution for this error checking ?

Comment: I am trying to control error checking for my application online .. not to check my own code

Comment: What do you mean by "control error checking for my application online?" Where does this code come from? It is user-entered?

Comment: Yes .. it is used-entered .. so I need to implement a function for it

Comment: Then just use [the browser bundle](http://www.jshint.com/install/). Be **very** careful with accepting & executing arbitrary JavaScript code, however, as this is a massive security hole.

Comment: @MattBall—users can execute arbitrary code anyway. In this case, perpahs JSON.parse can be used to convert the string to an array? Nope, can't handle elided members. :-(

Comment: @RobG not a terrible idea, though that might be too strict (for instance: rejecting single quotes as string delimiters).

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are trying to validate user-entered data, I'd suggest reevaluating your approach.

You should not require end-users to enter data in valid JavaScript syntax; this is annoying to your users.

Instead, I'd just have a textarea and instructions.

[image: mockup]

This is far easier for humans to deal with, and parsing is super simple:

```
var cars = document.getElementById('carstextarea').value.split('\n');
// => ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jslint takes a JavaScript source and scans it ,

visual studio, netbeans or eclipse have a plugin for that.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I am trying to control error checking for my application online .. not to check my own code

Answer (score 0):

Your second `cars` example with the `*` in it won't compile.

To check for double commas, you can iterate over the array and check for an undefined value.

```
for(var i = 0; i<cars.length; i++) {
if(cars[i] === undefined) {
// do something
}
}
```

Alternatively you could try and catch this before you generate the array. Is there a way to check for an empty row inputted by the user?