# How can I deal with this kind of bug in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

How can I make sure that two commas are not entered in an Array .. this is for a web application that generates an array from user input and it's a text field .. I cant change it to anything else.

example ..  `var names=["Kim",,"Andrew","Ashley"];`

in this array , we have two consecutive commas, instead of one .. how can i make sure that if the user enters any character that wouldn't be good , I just take it out .. like comma , dot, etc .. for the example of the extra comma , how would this be achieved considering that I have no other option but deal with a text field generating an array like this

Comment: In what way is this _not_ a duplicate of [your earlier question which I answered?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15621232/139010)

Comment: I'm asked to actually manipulate it myself in the code ..

Comment: The extra comma can be handled as in [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626836/139010). What other sorts of "invalid" input do you need to be able to handle, and _how_ do you need to handle it?

Comment: I want to downvote this but don't have the reputation to do that....see the other answers of your previous question and you should figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Run the array through a function (see below) to remove the invalid values in your array. In your case, the values are *undefined* for the second element in `["Kim",,"Andrew","Ashley"]`.

```
var stripEmpty = function (ary) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (ary[i] !== undefined) {
            result.push(ary[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
var names = ["Kim",,"Andrew","Ashley"];
var strippedNames = stripEmpty(names);    //  ["Kim","Andrew","Ashley"]
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/LymAZ/

Answer (score 0):

Two consecutive commas (or a leading comma) is an [elision](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4), it increments the index of the next member. The elided member doesn't exist as a property of the array. To find such members, you can use the `in` operator:

```
var a = [,0,1,,  , ,2,3,,  ,];

var i = a.length;

while (i--) {

  if (!(i in a)) {  // returns true if a has no index i
    a.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

alert(a); // 0,1,2,3
```

This also deals with extra spaces in the array literal.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug per say, it's just that you are having null entries from your form being added to your array. try this:

```
//assume your array has been filled up

var mod_names = names.join("#"); // you can use any delimeter apart from '#'

if(mode_names.indexOf(" ") > -1){
  mode_names.replace(/\s+/gi, "");
}
mode_names.replace(/#/gi, " ");
mod_names = mod_names.split(); // the default is a space char
names = mode_names;
```